# Openserver download page, but it must load it

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, localserver

I have installed OpenServer program to modify old company WordPress site locally.
So old WP page was on 5.6 PHP version, and put the same in OpenServer settings.

But program doesn't load page, but always try to download some "download" file. If try to open that file in notepad, it looks like usual index.php (what load WP).

So i played with .htaccess, server see it, but cant load php by some reason.

Same way i created clean WP doimain folder, what works. And just if i change php and apache version it didnt see MySQL DB.

What it may be ? If you need some screens, i can make them.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in .htaccess file.
By default it was ->
**AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php5 .html**

I was changed it to ->
**AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php5 .html**

Page loads now correctly by browser.